# How to make a report from this table below? (laravel mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have 2 tables like this:
there are request table and process table, the request table have an enum of type (TOP,LOW). the process table is the process of the request (from status 1 to 3).

**Table Image :**

[image: table image]

i want to make a report like this table below, how do i achieve this in laravel or in an sql queries?

**Table Report :**

[image: table report]

from the image above the type TOP has 2 data (id 1 and 2 from request table). in the process table, latest status of request_id = 1 is 3 and request_id = 2 is 2.

so in the report table the TOP data status = 2 is counted to be 1 (request_id = 2) and the TOP data status = 3 is counted to be 1 (request_id = 1). if the request_id = 2 is updated to be in process status 3 in table process, then the report count will show the TOP data status = 3 is counted to be 2 (request_id = 1&2).

I hope you all understand what my problem is, I'm trying to explain this problem in as much detail as possible. thank you

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

This query will work but could be further optimized like the inner query in selectRaw could be replaced by joins.

```
Request::select('type')
->selectRaw('(select count(id) from process where request_id IN (select id from requests r where type=requests.type) and status=1') as status1)

->selectRaw('(select count(id) from process where request_id IN (select id from requests r where type=requests.type) and status=2') as status2)

->selectRaw('(select count(id) from process where request_id IN (select id from requests r where type=requests.type) and status=3') as status3)
->groupBy('type')->get();
```

Comment: is the code correct? because i got error in the sql syntax near 'select count(id) from process where request_id IN (select id from requests r'